# Splunk relative times with + are incorrect in dashboard (out by a week)

Tags: splunk

Here is a test Splunk dashboard (using Splunk 8.0.4.1):

```
<dashboard>
  <label>test</label>
  <init>
    <eval token="argh1">now()</eval>
    <eval token="argh2">relative_time(now(), "-1s")</eval>
    <eval token="argh3">relative_time(now(), "+1s")</eval>
  </init>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <html>
        <h2>Dates ((Now $argh1$ -1s $argh2$ +1s $argh3$))</h2>
      </html>
    </panel>
  </row>
</dashboard>
```

I would expect this to show me three times in Unix epoch format - the current time, then a number 1 less, then a number 1 more than the first number. Here is an actual result:

```
Dates ((Now 1608304399 -1s 1608304398 +1s 1607699600))
```

As you can see, argh2 is indeed 1 less than current time, but argh3 is not 1 more; instead, it's substantially less. In fact it's exactly a week earlier than the 'now' time, plus one second.

This happens for any '+' time specification, +1w or +1d etc.

If I do the same thing inside a Splunk query on the same server:

```
index=aws | eval argh1=now() | eval argh2=relative_time(now(), "-1s") | eval argh3=relative_time(now(), "+1s")
```

Then it works fine, I can look inside the results and see argh3 is 1 second after argh1.

I believe it uses the local computer time zone for dashboard pages which might make a difference but my computer time is correct. I tried in Firefox and Chrome on my Windows 10 PC in case the browser made any difference, but with the same results.

Does anyone else know what's going on? (Note: I don't have admin access to this Splunk install but I can probably ask the person who does.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're seeing, but the lone example on Docs.Splunk for [`relative_time`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.1/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#relative_time.28X.2CY.29) uses a negative value.

That said, if you want to "look into the future" with your searches, why not just add 1 to `argh1` - since you've already `eval`'d it, you "know" it's `now()`.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
| eval argh1=now()
| eval argh2=argh1-1, argh3=argh1+1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, you're right that would work fine in this case, but I should have explained that this is a simplified example. What I actually want to do is a few cases simlar to relative_time(now(), '+1d@d') which you can't do with simple addition because of the rounding to a day start and also because of DST changes.